# anchor build error on mac m1

Tags: anchor

I've got error below when try to run "anchor build"

```
zsh 1096  (git)-[main]-% anchor build
BPF SDK: /Users/medici/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.10.31/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: command failed: 'cargo': Bad CPU type in executable (os error 86)
```

- solana-test-validator is OK
- anchor init is OK

i use solana 1.10.31 and anchor 0.25.0 installed with avm on mac m1. not sure what cause the problem. anything else i need to do to get anchor build on M1? any ideas please?

Comment: Does this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408379

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be if someone had specific insight on how to troubleshoot and let you build natively (I'd be interested as well), but I have faced this same issue on my M1, and had to fallback to using Rosetta.

This can be done through: `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`.

Edit: I tried several recent version of solana during the process, to no avail

Comment: just guessing here, but I'd put money on rosetta being the cause, rather than the solution to the problem.  OP's error message sounds a lot like attempting to execute and `x86_64` binary in an `aarch64` runtime environment

Comment: could be, although I had that same error and I did not have Rosetta installed at the time

Comment: This solved my issue (+1)

Comment: yeah, i also ended up with rosetta

Answer (score 0):

I am running Anchor on an M1 and not having any issues. I did not have to take any special steps due to running an M1. Your culprit is likely not hardware related.

Comment: hmm, which version of solana and anchor you use?

Comment: anchor = 0.25.0
solana = 1.10.29